# Image not shown in WebViewClient after Migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, html

I have a local html - file to show with WebViewClient / WebView.
One part of this html - file is:

```
<input name="aName" type="image" src="file:///storage/emulated/0/replaceWithTheApp/data/image.png" value="1">
```

before Migration to AndroidX the (png) - image is shown.

There are still other parts in the html referencing images, which are no longer shown.

Comment: Are you sure the image is well present ?

Comment: yes it exists exactly there! /storage/emulated/0/replaceWithTheApp/data/image.png

Answer (score 0):

I changed the html-Code from from file:// to an appropriate content://.

Tests with the Webview Implementation show that Version 70.0.3538.110 is still able to handle the file:// while newer Versions p.ex. the one with Chrome 92.0.4515.115 does not.